# How to read json response as name value pairs in JQuery

Tags: json, jquery, getjson

I want to read json response as name and value pairs in my JQuery code. Here is my sample JSON response that I return from my java code:

```
String jsonResponse = "{"name1":"value1", "name2:value2"};
```

in my JQuery, if I write `jsonResponse.name1`, I will get value as `"value1"`. Here is my JQuery code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/calculate',
    data: request, 
    success: function(responseData) {
        alert(responseData.name1);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //TODO  
    }
});
```

Here I want to read `"name1"` from jsonResponse instead of hardcoding in JQuery. Something like looping throug the response getting each name and value. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
success: function(responseData) {
    for (var key in responseData) {
        alert(responseData[key]);
    }
}
```

It is important to note that the order in which the properties will be iterated is arbitrary and shouldn't be relied upon.

Answer (score 7):

It's easy like this:

```
json = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" };

$.each(json, function(key, value) { alert(key + "=" + value); });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `responseData['name1']`. Easy.