# Handle PHP Array in Ajax Response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I send an AJAX request to a PHP file with this code:

```
$.post({
    url: "manage.php",
    dataType: "JSON"
}, {
    firtname: John, 
    lastname: edwin
}, function(data){
    $("#persons").html(data[0])
});
```

My PHP file returns data in an array such as this:

```
$a = 0;
while ($a < 5) 
{
    $data[$a] = "person".$a; 
    $a2++;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

I want to return data something like `$data[0] = "person 1";`. How can I handle this in AJAX? As you can see above currently I am trying `data[0]` but no success. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read json response as name value pairs in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858698/how-to-read-json-response-as-name-value-pairs-in-jquery)

Comment: Your `$.post` syntax is incorrect. See the documentation for more info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem. Sorry guys, there was a syntax error in my variable thats why i was not getting data in my ajax response. so the following code is correct & working

```
$.post({
url: "manage.php",
dataType: "JSON"
}, {
firtname: John, 
lastname: edwin
}, function(data){
$("#persons").html(data[0])
});
```

in my php file my Array variable was wrong thats why i was not getting data. sorry and thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post{'manage.php',{firstname:'John',lastname:'edwin'},function(data){
    $('#persons').html(data.0);
},'json');
```