# How to get values of the AJAX Response

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am not to getting the values from the result of the AJAX call. I return JSON but I do not know how to get a value. This is my code:

```
$.ajax({ 
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'queryProduct.php',
    data: { codigo: cod }                   
}).done(function(response){

    // How do it get values???
});
```

PHP file result:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM produccion.ma_producto WHERE codigo={$codigo}"; 
$result = pg_query($conn, $query);  

if (!$result) {
    echo "Error query: " . pg_last_error($conn);
} else {
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

From the first jquery call php file with ajax and after I would like to get the values and set to others elements....

Comment: `response` will already be parsed to an object for you as you set `dataType: 'json'`, so calling `JSON.parse()` again will be causing an error. Remove that line, and just use `response` as you would any normal object.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I have deleted the line, thanks! But I do not know how do get a value to use it?

Comment: make sure you pass array properly

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364091/parse-json-response-using-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858698/how-to-read-json-response-as-name-value-pairs-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row = pg_fetch_row($result)
 echo json_encode($row);`

Use above code in your PHP file.

Consider AJAX call returns this JSON Array.

i.e.

```
response = [
        {
            color: "red",
            value: "#f00"
        },
        {
            color: "green",
            value: "#0f0"
        },
        {
            color: "blue",
            value: "#00f"
        },
        {
            color: "cyan",
            value: "#0ff"
        },
        {
            color: "magenta",
            value: "#f0f"
        },
        {
            color: "yellow",
            value: "#ff0"
        },
        {
            color: "black",
            value: "#000"
        }
    ]
```

Now, after success of AJAX call you want to iterate through each JSON Object of this array, Where each Object is `{ color: 'someValue', value : 'someValue'}`. You can use `item.color` and `item.value` to access them.

You can do something like this:

```
 $.ajax({
 method: 'POST',
 dataType: 'json',
 url: 'queryProduct.php',
 data: { codigo: cod },
 success: function(response) {                                   
     console.log(response.pagino);
});
```

Here, response is your JSON Array and item represents an Object of JSON Array.

You can use `item.fieldName` to access each of your field from each JSON Object.

Comment: I do not understand well :(

Comment: can you tell me, what is returned in `response` by your AJAX call?

Comment: The idea is return a query of the queryProduct.php, you can see the code of the php file in my question. After return the query I do not know to use this values(in response variable)

Comment: Check the answer, i have modified with a little explanation.

Comment: Ok, I see it more clear. Could you tell me, how do it to know that kind of JSON(structure) have it? I am not sure that the PHP query returns a JSON object...

Comment: I see `echo json_encode($result);` this in your PHP Code. So, the result of your query is being encoded into JSON. Therefore, `response` object must be JSON, I am 100% sure.

Comment: Ok, for example:  I put this line: `alert(response.pagina)' but it show message 'undefined' and pagina is a field of the table of the query.

Comment: Use `item.pagina` not `response.pagina`

Comment: Do like this `$.each(response, function(key,item) { console.log(item.pagina); });`

Comment: I have tried but the developer console show this error message: jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 38

Comment: Is your database query returning a single record or multiple records?

Comment: The $result have been an array to set all values of fields?

Comment: I have updated AJAX call in asnwer.Check and try that.

Comment: Can you check and tell me the output of `console.log(response)` ?

Comment: Only it shows 38, is the codigo field but the query has nine fields

Comment: What does the statement `echo json_encode($result);` prints on your screen?

Comment: The same info, 38, it's the codigo field

Comment: Oh i got it, i guess. wait a second.

Comment: The problem was to $result, I do first to set in to array an after that show it. `$producto = pg_fetch_all($result);`

Comment: I have updated Answer. Check at the begining of the answer, hopefully that will work. You have to actually fetch your record from `$result`

Answer (score 0):

the values are within the callback function parameter "response", you can make an alert or a console.log and see them

```
$.ajax({ 
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'queryProduct.php',
    data: { codigo: cod }                   
}).done(function(response){
alert(response)
});
```

Comment: I have modified but only show me a field(codigo) but this query has nine fields!

Comment: can you do a var_dump within your php file and come back to us with the result?
var_dump(json_encode($result));

Comment: where it put the 'var_dump(json_encode($result));`?